# error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have to mention that there is no problem with my system's hardware because I also use Windows (as my system is dual boot) and Windows work fine.

Two days ago, all my applications were working fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Then, an automatic update came up and, as usual, I installed it. After that, all my applications have errors. Even today, after pressing on shut down, my system does not shut down. It just shows the Ubuntu home scree and I have to power it off through the power button.

Here is the error I get for `gnome-logs`:

```
gnome-logs: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am also sharing the picture of my terminal, in which you see that I have installed `libgtk`... But the problem is not gone.

[image: gnome-logs error showing]

And here is the same error for `gnome-calculator`:

[image: gnome calculator showing same error]

```
hina@hinakhadim2002:~$ dpkg -S libgtk-3.so.0
libgtk-3-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 
libgtk-3-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.2200.30 

hina@hinakhadim2002:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-logs gnome-calculator
gnome-logs: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 3.28.0-1 
Version table: 3.28.0-1 500
500 ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages 

gnome-calculator:
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 1:3.28.2-1~ubuntu18.04.3 
Version table: 
1:3.28.2-1~ubuntu18.04.3 500 500 
ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages 1:3.28.1-1ubuntu1 500 500 
ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

hina@hinakhadim2002:~$ snap list | grep gnome 
gnome-3-28-1804 3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498 116 latest/stable/… canonical* - 
gnome-calculator 3.36.0+git9.96b95fd2 748 latest/stable/… canonical* - 
gnome-characters v3.34.0+git5.918aab3 539 latest/stable/… canonical* - gnome-logs 3.34.0 100 latest/stable/… canonical* - 
gnome-system-monitor 3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7 145 latest/stable/… canonical* - hina@hinakhadim2002:~$
```

Comment: I'd suggest you backup your data and do an upgrade to 20.04. The problem should be gone and you'll get to enjoy the latest release.

Comment: @Béné there is no need to upgrade system which was normally operating before. It will create new problems with Qt4 and Python2 removal and so on. 
@ HinaKhadim - do you have gnome-logs installed as snap? Please add output of `apt-cache policy gnome-logs gnome-calculator` along with `snap list | grep gnome`. What is the output of `dpkg -S libgtk-3.so.0`? Have you had power outage? Did you tried to force filesystem check?

Comment: @Béné I want to upgrade to 20.04. but I can not back up my data. That's why I continue to ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @N0rbert yes, gnome-logs have installed as a snap. When I installed ubuntu 18.04, all snaps come with it. I have not separately installed these snaps. I have no power outage and I did not try to force filesystem check. These errors come after the updates comes two days before from ubuntu. Two days ago, I have opened my logs, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that problems are only happen with Snap'ed applications. Without gtk3 libraries you would not be able even to login to GUI session.

So I would suggest to save its list with

```
snap list
```

Then purge all of them by

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd
```

And install two problematic applications from deb-packages with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-logs gnome-calculator
```

Optionally you can install Snappy back with `sudo apt-get install snapd` and reinstall (some of) snaps back then.

Comment: Now, all snaps are working after reinstalling again as you mention

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me in a similar situation:

```
snap revert packagename
```

Apparently the most recent version was messed up somehow.